# How to Disable md-button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material, ui-validate

I have a form(HTML) and a directive to do stuff when submit button is clicked.The form has 10 input fields. The requirement is to keep the submit button which is a  disabled till the time user enters value in at least one field.

Can anyone please help me. Iam new to angular and could not find much help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply use `ng-disabled="true"`.

declare a function in your controller something like

`checkInputFields` which return either `true` or `false` depending on the form modal.

then use

```
<md-button ng-disabled="checInputFields()">
  Submit
</md-button>
```

Comment: i dont have a controller but the form is sitting in a directive. i tried your suggestion by putting a method in the directive but the directive has to know when a value is entered.

Comment: use `bindToController` in your directive and declare your method on the the controller of directive.

Answer (score 5):

```
  <form ng-submit="search()" name="searchSideNav">
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center">
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label>{{::labels.documentName}}</label>
        <input ng-model="searchItems.sDocumentName" ng-required="" name="sDocumentName">
        <div ng-show="searchSideNav.sDocumentName.$invalid && !searchSideNav.sDocumentName.$pristine">
          <p ng-show="searchSideNav.sDocumentName.$error.required" class="help-block">Document is required</p>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
       <md-button ng-disabled="searchSideNav.$invalid">
         Submit
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: tried that but is not working for some reason my form is not invalid

Comment: Please make sure all fields of form should have name attribute. Can you please post your form html here

Comment: <form ng-submit="search()" name="SearchSideNav">
                <div layout="column" layout-align="center">
                <md-input-container flex>
                    <label>{{::labels.documentName}}</label>
                    <input ng-model="searchItems.sDocumentName" ng-required="requireAtleastOneInput()">
                </md-input-container>
                <location-select label="{{::labels.location}}" location="selectedLocation"></location-select>
                <br/>

Comment: its just a portion of the html

Comment: @AlbertPinto I have updated my answer. Please focus on validation and form field's attribute. Validation does work only when you have added name attribute. Now it should work. Please check. Else i can create the plunker for you